# Approximation of a function with a polynomial of degree n.

Tags: approximation-theory, weak-derivatives

Let $f\in{L_{loc}^{1}}$ such that $\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)}{\phi}^{(n)}(x)dx=0$ for all $\phi\in{C_{0}^{\infty}}(a,b)$. Then how do we show there exists a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree less or equal to $n-1$ such that $f=P$ a.e.?

My try is: I showed the basic case that is if $\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)}{\phi}'(x)dx=0$ for all $\phi\in{C_{0}^{\infty}}(a,b)$ then $f$ is a.e. equal to a constant function. But I have no idea how to generalize this base result to the case for $n$ in general.

Answer (score 0):

Set $X_+=\{x:f(x)>0\}$ and $X_-=\{x:f(x)<0\}$. If any of them, say $X_+$, has positive measure, then it contains inner points and thus an open interval $(c,d)\subset [a,b]$. Now select a non-trivial non-negative $ϕ∈C^∞_0(a,b)$ with support inside $(c,d)$ and draw conclusions from $\int^b_af(x)ϕ^n(x)dx=0$.

Maybe there is something missing in the assumptions.

---

The corrected assumption is that $\int^b_af(x)ϕ^{(n)}(x)dx=0$ for any $ϕ∈C^∞_0(a,b)$. For the distributional interpretation see the comments.

Try a more elementary approach. Let $b_h$ be the box function that has value $1$ from $0$ to $h>0$. Then the convolution product $b_h*ϕ∈C^∞_0(a,b)$ inherits smoothness from $ϕ$ and the compact support from both factors united.
$$
(b_h*ϕ)'(x)=(b_h*ϕ')(x)=\int_0^h b_h(t) ϕ'(x-t)\,dt=\int_{x-h}^x ϕ'(s)\,ds=ϕ(x)-ϕ(x-h)
$$
and so
$$
\int_{\Bbb R}g(x)\,(b_h*ϕ)'(x)\,dx=\int_{\Bbb R}(g(x)-g(x+h))\,ϕ(x)\,dx=\int_{\Bbb R}((-Δ_h) g)(x)\,ϕ(x)\,dx
$$
Repeated application of this identity results in
$$
\int_{\Bbb R}f(x)\,((b_h*)^nϕ)^{(n)}(x)\,dx=\int_{\Bbb R}((-Δ_h)^n f)(x)\,ϕ(x)\,dx
$$
which means that $Δ_h^n f=0$ a.e. resulting in $f(x+kh)=p_{x,h}(x+kh)$ a.e., where $p_{x,h}$ is a polynomial of degree less than $n$.

Next to prove: $p_{x,h}$ is, a.e., independent of $x$ and $h$. Perhaps include some smoothing kernel in the convolution product, making the smoothed version of $f$ continuous and thus one polynomial everywhere...

Comment: @ Lutzl: Nothing is missing in the assumption for sure. How do you  get the conclusion from the last statement "Now select a non-trivial non-negative $ϕ∈C^∞_0(a,b)$ with support inside $(c,d)$ and draw conclusions from $\int^b_af(x)ϕ^n(x)dx=0$."

Comment: Both $f$ and $ϕ$ (or $ϕ^n$) are positive where $ϕ(x)\ne0$. So the integral should have a positive value, contradicting the assumption. Which means that both $X_+$ and $X_-$ must have measure zero, so that $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere. $0$ is of course a polynomial, but not of degree $n$.

Comment: If $ϕ^n$ was intended as a derivative, and not the $n$-th power, please write it traditionally as $ϕ^{(n)}$. Then the assumption is that $f^{(n)}=0$ in distributional derivatives, which means that $f^{(n)}$ is a regular distribution, i.e., a function in $L^1_{loc}$, and quite classically, the $n$-th anti-derivative of zero is a polynomial of degree at most $n$.

Comment: @ Lutzl: I am so sorry that it is $n^{th}$ derivative not the $n^{th}$ power. I apologize for that misunderstanding.

Comment: @ Lutzl: How we can repeat the identity you establish to get $$
\int_{\Bbb R}f(x)\,((b_h*)^nϕ)^{(n)}(x)\,dx=\int_{\Bbb R}((-Δ_h)^n f)(x)\,ϕ(x)\,dx
?$$

Comment: Remember that for convolution products, the derivative of the product can be shifted to any of its factors, $(a*b)'=a'*b=a*b'$. And so $[(b_h*)^nϕ]^{(n)}(x) = ((b_h*)^n[ϕ^{(n)}])(x) = (b_h*[(b_h*)^{n-1}(ϕ^{(n-1)})]')(x)$.